# Suppose that $Y_1,Y_2$ are random samples of size 2 from a standard normal distribution. Find the distribution of $U =Y_1 + Y_2$

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $Y_1,Y_2$ are random samples of size 2 from a standard normal distribution. Find the distribution of $U =Y_1 + Y_2$.

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I am confused about how to interpret $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ as a sample from another distribution - we haven't discussed this in my class.

Answer (score 0):

$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is a random sample from some distribution means that these random variables are independent and have this distribution.

So you have independent $Y_1,Y_2$ with standard normal distribution. Can you give an answer now?